# How to define a variable $x$ such that $Abs[x]<1$ and use this globally without having to re-write it again and again?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, variable-definitions, assumptions

I am writing a code or a calculation of a very complicated function and my main variable is $x$ such that $-1<x<1$. This assumption has to simplify my final answer a lot, but since the final answer is very complicated (20-30 lines!), the FullSimplify condition does not return anything back and if I use the assumption at the end of the calculation, it again does not give anything back (it runs forever).

So, I have broken the calculation down to small bits, where in every small part I calculate a function of $x$. But, I do not want to re-evaluate the result of each function by re-writing the assumption $Abs[x]<1$. Is there a way to define $x$ at the start of the code such that whenever there is an $x$ is the code, Mathematica will take it to be such that $Abs[x]<1$? I.e., can I define $x$ with this condition globally?

Comment: Have you seen [`$Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html)?  (It will only be applied to functions that use assumptions.)

Comment: I have always used it for simplifying a result. But, I do not know how to impose the assumptions globally (i.e. whenever the program sees $x$, it will know, before even doing the calculation that $Abs[x]<1$ and will simplify by itself the calculation based on the assumption).

Comment: I don't have a clear idea what you're after. Some functions, such as `Solve` and `Maximize`, require the constraints to be explicitly listed. Strictly speaking, then, the answer to your question is "No." Some functions do no simplification, and `$Assumptions` will have no effect even if they could simplify the problem.  Functions that call `Simplify` internally will apply `$Assumptions` when `Simplify` is called; there are other functions that use assumptions in the same way, also.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Well, most of my functions are defined with respect to derivatives of $x$. But, when I get the results of these derivatives, there are simplifications that can be done when I use the assumption $Abs[x]<1$. My end result is a sum of these functions of derivatives. So, I do not want to use assumptions after the calculation of every function. I am just asking if there is a way for mathematica to know that whenever it finds $x$, it should assume that $Abs[x]<1$.